# watir webdriver on linux

Tags: jenkins, webdriver, watir

We are using a combination of watir webdriver, firefox and jenkins on as5 servers to test our frontend.  I currently have 15+ various transactional tests that run every couple of minutes.   I'm frequently having issues with watir failing to open a firefox browser due to the locking port not getting released in a reasonable amount of time.  I've put in random sleep delays and additional launches (if the first failed) to help allieve these issues but it's still a big problem.

Is there anyway to just leave firefox running and have the tests simply open a new tab, run their steps and close the tab when done?   On a loaded server, it is taking up to 20 seconds to simply launch a browser.

If not, are there better ways to launch firefox so it isn't so heavy?

I get that we aren't using watir in a way that it was intended, but our hopes are to make it a feasible alternative to commercial solutions which can be prohibitively expensive.

Thanks for any input you can provide.